# Return from then - nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise

I am sort of new to NodeJS and I'm learning as I code but I can't wrap my head around Promise/then.

Here is the piece of code - I'm using a library function to Read database values.

```
var collection = 'Students';
var query = {};
query.name = 'name';

  //readFromDatabse returns -{Function} a promise to return the document found, or null if not found
var temp = readFromDatabase(collection, query).then(function(studentData) {
    var result = {
        resultDetails: {
            username: studentData.username,
            password: studentData.password
        }
    };
    return callback(null,resultDetails);

});
```

but when I read see the values in temp, it contains     `{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":false}`!! how can I get the result details into temp?

Comment: not the issue, but `return callback(null,resultDetails);` wont do what you expect, because `resultDetails` is undefined - also, the fact that you're using a callback in a promise suggests other potential issues - I said potential, the code could be just fine, it's just that promises are usually used instead of the callback paradigm

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of Promises as containers for values. `readFromDatabase` returns such a container, which might eventually hold the requested value unless the query fails. Your `temp` variable points to the container, but not the response. The properties `isFullfilled` and `isRejected` are attributes of the Promise telling you that it has neither been resolved with a value or rejected with an error.

To get to the response you have to use the `then` method. The function you register there will be called for you, when the query yields a result or an error.

```
var collection = 'Students';
var query = {};
query.name = 'name';

var temp = null;
readFromDatabase(collection, query).then(function(studentData) {
    var result = {
        resultDetails: {
            username: studentData.username,
            password: studentData.password
        }
    };
    temp = result;
});

// temp is still null here
```